# RPN Calculator in C

Tags: c, calculator, rpn

Can someone please explain why I keep getting gibberish after I use strok() on myString? A picture of my output is at the bottom. I tried initializing every single element in myString to be a NULL character but my code still doesnt work :(

Expected Output:

[image]

My Output :

[image]

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    char myString[60];
    char *token;
    float result;
    float x;
    float y;
    struct Stack myStack;
    StackInit(&myStack);


    BOARD_Init();

    printf("\nWelcome to my RPN calculator.\n");
    printf("Enter floats and + - / * in RPN format: \n >");

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof (myString); i++) {
        myString[i] = '\0';
    }

    fgets(myString, sizeof (myString), stdin);



    token = strtok(myString, " ");
    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("%f\n", atof(token));
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");

        if (atof(token) != 0) {
            StackPush(&myStack, atof(token));
        } else if (*token == '+') { // if token is addition
            StackPop(&myStack, &y);
            StackPop(&myStack, &x);
            result = x + y;
            StackPush(&myStack, result);

        } else if (*token == '-') { // if token is subtraction
            StackPop(&myStack, &y);
            StackPop(&myStack, &x);
            result = x - y;
            StackPush(&myStack, result);
        } else if (*token == '*') { // if token is multiplication
            StackPop(&myStack, &y);
            StackPop(&myStack, &x);
            result = x * y;
            StackPush(&myStack, result);
        } else if (*token == '/') { // if token is division
            StackPop(&myStack, &y);
            StackPop(&myStack, &x);
            result = x / y;
            StackPush(&myStack, result);
        }

    }




while (1);
```

}

Comment: Please do not post images of text output. Paste it as text within the question itself. That allows others to more easily copy it for reference in comments/questions.

Comment: Also, please post a [mcve]. We can't comment on code that we can't see. Complete code also allows us to run it and see/debug the program for ourselves.

Comment: `while (token != NULL) {
        printf("%f\n", atof(token));
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");` : The first token is discarded.

Comment: Have some relevant code been removed? Can't see how this code can produce the said output.

Comment: Sorry @kaylum first time posting on this site. What do you mean @BLUEPIXY?

Comment: @JohnSnow - Your posted code can't produce the output you have posted. You should fix that. The problem BLUEPIXY pointed out was related to your original code. In that code you call `strtok` inside the loop before you used the value of `token` that you obtained outside the loop. In other words: `token = strtok(NULL, " ");` should be the very last line inside the loop.

Comment: thank you @4386427, can you explain how what I did was wrong? I'm such a newb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @BLUEPIXY in a comment, your code has a problem here:

```
token = strtok(myString, " ");   // Here you get the first sub string
while (token != NULL) {
    printf("%f\n", atof(token));
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");   // Here you get the second sub string
                                 // and throw away the first substring
                                 // So all the code below is never executed
                                 // for the first substring.
                                 // In other words: You never push the first
                                 // float to the stack

    if (atof(token) != 0) {
        StackPush(&myStack, atof(token));
```

What you should do instead is to move `token = strtok(NULL, " ");` to the end of the loop:

```
while (token != NULL) {
    printf("%f\n", atof(token));
    // Not here............. token = strtok(NULL, " ");

    if (atof(token) != 0) {
        StackPush(&myStack, atof(token));
    } else if (*token == '+') { // if token is addition
    //...
    //...
    }

    token = strtok(NULL, " ");    // but here
}
```

Comment: i added a printf ("%f", myStack); before the token = strtok(NULL, " ");  and my result is printing out three times, would you happen to know why?

Comment: @JohnSnow - `printf ("%f", myStack);` ? That should give you a big warning! You can't print a `struct` using `%f` - that is only for floats and doubles. You should always turn on all warnings. For `gcc` always use `gcc -Wall ...`

Comment: it does give me an error but how would i print out only the last thing on my stack? would i just return result; ?

Comment: @JohnSnow - I can't tell as I don't have the code for the stack. But perhaps you could do: `float t = StackPop(..); printf("%f", t); StackPush(.., t) ;` i.e. pop the element, print it, push it back again. Anyway - I think you should ask a new question for that part.